# Moved Outlook messages still show up in Inbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Starting a few months ago in Office 365 ProPlus v1902, whether moving emails manually or via a macro [below] from `Inbox` to another folder of my Exchange account [`MyFolder`], I see behavioral issues:

```vb
Sub MoveMessage(oOlObj As Object, oOlFoldTrg As Outlook.Folder, Optional conf As Boolean = False)
  ...
  oOlObj.Move oOlFoldTrg
  ...
End Sub
```

1. **Unexpected:**

   1. Email still shows in `Inbox` when typing anything in the search bar that matches the email
   2. With email selected *from the Search Results list*, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> shows *Properties*, including *Location - Inbox*
2. **Expected:** *(inconsistent with the above)*

   1. Compared to 1.1, the email does not show in `Inbox` normally without searches
   2. Opening the email via <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, and going to *File*, shows the correct location of the email [`MyFolder`] as the second item
   3. When navigating to `MyFolder`, the email is there
   4. Compared to 1.2, *From the Folder View*, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> shows *Properties*, including *Location - MyFolder*

**How can I get rid of this behavior, as I assume it's not normal?** 
 **What do others see with accounts of various types (Exchange, IMAP, POP)?**

- Related from Spiceworks:

  - [Deleted Private Inbox Message Still Available](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1995542-deleted-private-inbox-message-still-available?started_from=new_topic)
  - [Outlook lags when moving inbox messages to subfolders](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1376106-outlook-lags-when-moving-inbox-messages-to-subfolders)

Comment: I tested in my environment but cannot reproduce your issue. Are you sure you are moving and not copying? In this situation, this may be a error in outlook update, it is suggested to upgrade your Outlook to the lasted version and see if there is any difference.

Comment: @Aidan - If I had copied instead of moved, items 2.1 and 2.2 shouldn't happen.

Comment: How are you moving the email - manually or by rule? If by rule then add more info.

Comment: @harrymc - I am not using rules.
I am either moving them manually, or with a macro, see edit.
I didn't pay attention to whether this happens in one case or the other (I would think `Move` does exactly the same as moving manually). If you think this may be relevant, I can try a few times.

Comment: @harrymc - Note that:
1) Aside from my stated uncertainty, I can "eyeball" that this happens in both cases, and most/all of the times.
What I do not recall is if I had lately *any instance* when this problem did not happen, so my first guess is that is always.
2) Both methods worked for me as intended for several years now. This issue only started a short time ago, and I cannot identify precisely what changed.

Comment: Did you try to repair or uninstall/reinstall Outlook?

Comment: It would be important to know whether this happens with IMAP accounts, POP3 accounts or Exchange accounts. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @harrymc - No, I did not try repairing/reinstalling.
This is something I want to get fixed, but not at the potential cost of screwing something else.
I would rather not taking these chances.

Comment: @Binarus - This is an Exchange account.

Comment: In the meantime, do moved emails still come up in search much later, or only soon after the move?

Comment: @harrymc - I confirm that:
1) This happens with emails moved either manually or with my macro.
2) An email from 7/13 (which was moved a couple of days later at most) still shows in my inbox when searching.
I **guess** this is not normal behavior, do you not see the same?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Does this happen if you remove then re-add your exchange account to Outlook? Close Outlook, rename the Exchange `.pst` database file, then re-open Outlook and re-add account _(DO NOT delete the old `.pst` and DO NOT make any changes OR send any emails from the `.pst` when you re-add the account, as you'll be deleting the new `.pst` if the issue still exists)_. Due to Exchange accounts being entirely different and more complex than all other types, copy and paste your question onto the [Spiceworks forum](https://community.spiceworks.com/).

Comment: Try to rebuild the Outlook search index in *File > Options >  Search > Indexing Options > Advanced >  Rebuild*.

Comment: @JW0914 - Your edit changed the meaning of what changes *might* have caused the new behavior. Please accommodate that.
Plus, I usually boldface the questions so they stand out and it's easier to read.

Comment: @harrymc - Your comment is the same as pointed at in https://superuser.com/questions/1531602/moved-outlook-messages-still-show-up-in-inbox#comment2407110_1580088
It seems I can not do that now due to permissions/policies.

Comment: @JW0914 - Posted at https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2285726-moved-outlook-messages-still-show-up-in-inbox (with some markdown from here that I don't know how to replace).

Comment: If you lack permissions, perhaps you could get an administrator to help.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I forgot to include "[below]" after "macro", adding it when I edited to apply correct markdown for web links. Just an FYI, sentences should never be broken up by a code box, as it discombobulates - complete sentences can go before/after a code box but never be split by one. _(For code boxes on Spiceworks, use the formatting toolbar [`</>` button], with the likely syntax language being `VB.Net`; Spiceworks uses HTML markdown, which isn't used as the main markdown on StackExchange, so some markdown, like `<kbd>`, isn't transferable - change `<br>` to `<br> </br>`)_

Answer (score 0):

I have stopped using Outlook several years ago, but I think I can perhaps give a few tips. Let's look at the problem from a purely logical point of view:

Obviously, there are differences between the live data and the data which is shown when searching. This nearly always means that there is a problem with indexing. As far as I know, Outlook uses the Windows Indexer for its searching, and as far as I can remember, there are a few options to manage the indexing behavior.

In other words, I suspect that the indexing has stopped running properly at the time when this began to happen. Another reason could be that you have set up a new data file in Outlook and didn't add it to indexing.

There is [this page on the Microsoft website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshooting-outlook-search-issues-2556b11f-f4d8-46be-b0a7-de33a3f4f066) which explains what to do when there are search / indexing issues in Outlook. Many of these tips are nonsense (e.g. reinstall Office), but quite a few are good. For example, I personally would follow items 2 through 7 (and eventually 8) in the section titled "Outlook search returns no results" (I have understood that this is not your exact problem, but I am quite sure that the issues described there could also cause the behavior you encounter).

If you are working with shared mailboxes, you should eventually follow the steps shown in the section titled "Shared Mailbox: Problems with search results".

As a final note, I am aware that it is bad style to just provide a link, but in this case, the original text is quite long and mixed with images, which would clutter this answer too much if I would cite it completely. Everybody who disagrees should let me know, so that I can reconsider this decision.

Comment: Though I understand why you don't want to cite paragraphs from that link, I think you should cite at least part as Microsoft (and other websites) tens to change some URLs..

Comment: The only item from 2-7 that possibly correlates with finding in Inbox elements that were moved from there is #7 "Rebuild the search catalog", assuming there is something wrong with the catalog; new emails are actually incorporated into the results (with the same problem, of course).
So far I could not do that.

Comment: Are there any differences in running the search server-side versus running the search locally?

Comment: @Binarus - I wouldn't know how to run it server-side. I have Outlook in my PC, which I guess is my email client, and all that I posted applies to that instance.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Since you are using Outlook / Exchange, here are a few starting points regarding this; please have a look into Allen Wang's answer there *and the links he gave in his other contributions*: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dbba3249-2a95-4ea0-942f-df9854d6e5eb/serverside-search-in-cached-mode?forum=Exch2016CM